# How can I make a discord bot that will DM new users when they join the server?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, dm

So basically I've been working on this one bot for my server, I want it to DM the users that join the server, Like whenever a user joins my server, they would receive a DM by my bot?
I have used this code now, but it doesn't seem to work, can anyone help?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready!');


bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    member.send("Welcome to the server!")
        .catch(console.error);

    });});

client.login('<token>');
```

Comment: no, please, don't. those bots are so annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using wrong way it is `client` not `bot`. Cause you are initial your bot as `client` since `const client = new Discord.Client()`;. And there is no need to wrap it in `ready` event

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready!');
});

client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    console.log("new member join")
    member.send("Welcome to the server!").catch(console.error);
});


client.login('<token>');
```

Comment: Oh, I see but when I added the code that you edited and have pasted here, It gave me an error and it still doesn't seem to work, The bot came online but when any user joins it doesn't dm anything.

Comment: Try my new edit code check if it log data

Comment: Make sure that when you invite the bot, it has the "server members intent" box checked

Answer (score 0):

With the updated changes (in v14), the enums have changed to Pascal case, and the intents need to be specified like the following:

```
Intents: Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES -> GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
```

This is my code which sends a dm to the user:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client(
    { intents: [GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers], partials: [Partials.Channel] });
const token = 'token';

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
  member.send('Welcome to the server! Feel free to introduce yourself and enjoy your stay.');
});

client.login(token);
```

Additionally, you need to enable the "Server Members Intent" and "Presence Intent" for your bot in the Discord Developer Portal:

1. Go to the Discord Developer Portal:
   https://discord.com/developers/applications Select your application.
2. Navigate to the "Bot" tab. Scroll down to the "Privileged Gateway
   Intents" section.
3. Enable both "Server Members Intent" and "Presence Intent."